# A4J richfaces 3 doesn't work

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jboss5.x, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I am using JBoss 5.01 and richfaces: 3.3. When the first **h:selectOneMenu id="codOrgao"** changes, I need to get the year value of the second **h:selectOneMenu id="ano"** and then load the **third h:selectOneMenu id="codMembro"**. That is the code that I wrote, I don't know the reason, but  doesn't work.

a4j supporte doesn't work(in valueChangeListener="#{populaMembros.pegaListaMembros} class I wrote a simple System.out.println("listener called")" to see if that method is called but it isn't ). Thanks in advance for any help!!!

```
<h:form styleClass="labelPorCima">
<h:panelGrid id="mpanel">   

        <div class="content field">
            <label for="codOrgao">Selecione um orgão</label>    
            <h:selectOneMenu id="codOrgao" styleClass="textoLongo" valueChangeListener="#{populaMembros.pegaListaMembros}">                                                                                             
                <f:selectItems  value="#{populaOrgaosBean.listaItensOrgaos}" />
                <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="codMembro"/>    
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="ano" styleClass="inputNome">               
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2012"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2011"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2010"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2009"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2008"/>                
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <div class="content field ">
            <label for="membro" class="membro">Nome do Membro</label>               
            <h:selectOneMenu id="codMembro" styleClass="inputNome" disabled="true">                                              
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um membro" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>

</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `onclick` instead of `onchange`? Onchange fires when the menu loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

1. `codOrgao` won't fire it's value change listener because it doesn't have a `value` attribute. The component needs to have a `value` attribute, bound to a backing bean variable
2. You should move the `actionListener` from the `<h:selectOneMenu/>` to the `<a4j:support/>`.

So in all, your code should look like:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="codOrgao" value="#{bean.theValue}" styleClass="textoLongo">                                                                                             
     <f:selectItems  value="#{populaOrgaosBean.listaItensOrgaos}" />
     <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="codMembro" actionListener="#{populaMembros.pegaListaMembros}"/>    
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```